# Getting custom aoColumns definition from server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, server-side, datatables

I'm trying to define aoColumns using ajax and a C# webmethod. I am treating it very similarly to how I am passing in server-side data, using a List> data structure that I add rows of List to. My problem is that this results in a string like:

```
{\"aoColumns\":[[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": False\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"],[\"\\\"bVisible\\\": True\"]]}
```

Which is nearly correct, except that the column definitions are using square brackets instead of `{}`. How would I go about generating the correct JSON text? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you get this text in your example?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using data tables from http://www.datatables.net/. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am not sure I understand if you are having trouble creating the JSON string to return to the AJAX call or converting it into something usable on the server-side.

If you are going to create a JSON string in a web method, I would suggest using a Dictionary type, since they are so close to JSON strings. To convert a Dictionary type into a JSON string, use this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
// add values here...
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dictionary);
```

If you are converting a JSON string into a Dictionary object, use this:

```
var dictionary = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

Another thing I like to do is convert the dictionary into an array if I am going to be working with any keys or values since getting them from the dictionary can be a pain when you do not know the exact key value you want to work with.

For reference, the JavaScriptSerializer is part of the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer namespace and in the System.Web.Extensions assembly.